# Keep iAd view on all the pages/views in Titanium

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, iad, titanium-alloy

On Titanium 3.X (+Alloy), I created an iAd View

```
var iAd = Ti.UI.iOS.createAdView({
        width: '100%',
        height: 'auto'});
```

And for each pages called via `anOtherPage.open()`, I recreate the iAdView.
The problem is that when I enter the new page, the previous iAdView disappears before reappearing. How can I make it so that the iAdView never disappears from a page to an other.

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple Guidelines

> A standard banner takes up a small area of the screen and is often
>   visible for as long as the screen is visible. You choose the app
>   screens that should display a standard banner and make room for the
>   banner view in the layout.

check the  [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/iAdRichMediaAds.html)